# How does avr-gcc linker know to put the `.data`section at `0x800100` rather than `0x800060`?

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-script

Looking at the linker script for my part (ATMEGA168PD), the `data` region has an origin defined as starting at `0x800060`...

```
MEMORY
{
  text   (rx)   : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = __TEXT_REGION_LENGTH__
  data   (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x800060, LENGTH = __DATA_REGION_LENGTH__
  eeprom (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x810000, LENGTH = __EEPROM_REGION_LENGTH__
  fuse      (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x820000, LENGTH = __FUSE_REGION_LENGTH__
  lock      (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x830000, LENGTH = __LOCK_REGION_LENGTH__
  signature (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x840000, LENGTH = __SIGNATURE_REGION_LENGTH__
  user_signatures (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x850000, LENGTH = __USER_SIGNATURE_REGION_LENGTH__
}
```

The `.data` output section does not explicitly define an address, but instead only refers to the `data` region ...

```
  .data          :
  {
     PROVIDE (__data_start = .) ;
    *(.data)
     *(.data*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.d*)
    *(.rodata)  /* We need to include .rodata here if gcc is used */
     *(.rodata*) /* with -fdata-sections.  */
    *(.gnu.linkonce.r*)
    . = ALIGN(2);
     _edata = . ;
     PROVIDE (__data_end = .) ;
  }  > data AT> text
```

...yet the `.data` output section ends up at the address `0x800100` rather than `0x800060`...

```
00800100 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
```

This turns out to be the correct address for the start of the `.data` segment on this part because `0x800060-0x8000ff` is reserved for some registers and is not general purpose RAM.

There is no origin in the linker script that would specify the `0x800100` address and there are no command line parameters to the linker that would tell it this magic, part specific number. There are no other output sections in the `data` region that could be pushing the `.data` output section higher in memory to the `0x800100` location (`.bss` and `.noinit` both follow `.data` and are relative to it).

I've also noticed that if I rename the `.data` out section to anything else, its origin lands at the beginning of the `data` region at `0x800060` as expected. Somehow the linker knows that an output section specifically named `.data` must start specifically origin `0x800100` rather than the start of the region specified in the linker script.

It is as if somewhere there is a `.data = 0x800100;` or `-Tdata=0x80010`, but I can not find it anywhere!

My question is: How does the linker know to start the `.data` addresses at `0x800100` for this part?

Comment: This is not specific to electronics and may get a better answer over on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Point well taken, but although it is a gcc/ld question, it is specific to this specific AVR hardware part and revolves around the hardware memory layout of this part and how the tools are configured to address it, so feels more likely to find the right people here (maybe!).

Answer (score 2):

I found it! It is in the *device specs* file that `gcc` apparently automatically pulls in based on the `-mmcu` setting. In my case, the `ATMEGA168PB` file included...

```
*link_data_start:
    -Tdata 0x800100
```

...which overrides the memory region in the linker script.

Full documentation for these device spec files is here...

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to figure out where the value of the `0x800100` for the origin of `.data` was coming from, so as a work around I commented out the standard `data` region and instead defined a new region called `dataX` that started at the beginning of usable RAM...

```
MEMORY
{
  text   (rx)   : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = __TEXT_REGION_LENGTH__
 /* data   (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x800060, LENGTH = __DATA_REGION_LENGTH__ */
  dataX   (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x800100, LENGTH = __DATA_REGION_LENGTH__ 
  eeprom (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x810000, LENGTH = __EEPROM_REGION_LENGTH__
  fuse      (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x820000, LENGTH = __FUSE_REGION_LENGTH__
  lock      (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x830000, LENGTH = __LOCK_REGION_LENGTH__
  signature (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x840000, LENGTH = __SIGNATURE_REGION_LENGTH__
  user_signatures (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x850000, LENGTH = __USER_SIGNATURE_REGION_LENGTH__
}
```

Then I changed all of the sections that used to refer to the `data` region to instead refer to this new region while also changing the name of the `.data` output section to be `.dataX` so it would not crash into the predefined value...

```
  .dataX    : 
  {
     PROVIDE (__data_start = .) ;
    *(.data)
     *(.data*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.d*)
    *(.rodata)  /* We need to include .rodata here if gcc is used */
     *(.rodata*) /* with -fdata-sections.  */
    *(.gnu.linkonce.r*)
    . = ALIGN(2);
     _edata = . ;
     PROVIDE (__data_end = .) ;

  }  > dataX AT> text


  __data_load_start = LOADADDR(.dataX);
   __data_load_end = __data_load_start + SIZEOF(.dataX);

  /* Global data not cleared after reset.  */

  .noinit    :  
  {
     PROVIDE (__noinit_start = .) ;
    *(.noinit*)
     PROVIDE (__noinit_end = .) ;
     _end = . ;
     PROVIDE (__heap_start = .) ;
  }  > dataX
```

I noticed that the `ld` documentation says...

> The load address of the section is set to the next free address in the
>   region, aligned to the section’s alignment requirements.

...so I also took out all of the origin calculations for all of these input sections that looked like this...

`.noinit  ADDR(.bss) + SIZEOF (.bss)  :  AT (ADDR (.noinit))`

...since these calculations are unnecessary (and in fact break when the order of the sections is changed). Instead now the script just lets the linker automatically assign each section to the next aligned address in the requested region.

Everything now works correctly, the sections in the `data` region now always start at the real beginning of RAM, and the script does not break when the sections are changed.

That said, out of curiosity I would still love to understand where that origin of `0x800100` for `.data` is coming from if you know!